# Delphi packed object - broken backward compatibility

Tags: delphi

I'm moving one old project from Delphi 7 to 2007 and it's seems that packed objects

```
type
  TMyTime = packed object
  private
    Year: Word;
    Month: Byte;
    Day: Byte;
    Hour: Byte;
    Minute: Byte;
    Milliseconds: Word;
  end;
```

generates

> [Pascal Error] *.pas(x): E2006 PACKED not allowed here

error in D2007.

May somebody tell me which Delphi version have broken packed object compatibility?

Comment: It compiles in XE2 also. But not in D2010. Don't have XE at hand here. You should use a record for this type. You should also not pack it because that makes performance worse. If you absolutely have to pack, and absolutely have to use `object`, then use `{$ALIGN 1}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [QC10279 "packed object" compilation error](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=10279) we can see that the bug was reported in D2005 and was fixed in XE2.

Comment: ... and in all cases, `object` is deprecated and [buggy has hell](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/01/29/record-and-object-issue-in-Delphi-2010). Stay away from it if you can - even if [I'm a big fan of `object`](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/08/06/Save-object%2C-stop-class-hegemony%21), since we loose inheritance with the new extended `record` type...

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, actually I was surprised that the object model was ported from TP to Delphi. Never found a good use for it. Records are fine and much better now with the extended (from D2006?) possibilities and also the helper declarations. I can live without the missing inheritance.

Comment: It is very efficient to have stack-allocated or array-allocated data structures. `TObject` has an overhead, and add memory fragmentation, which is sometimes not needed. In practice, `record` does not support inheritance, whereas I like very much how `object` may inherit. I do not speak of TP7 `object` virtual methods, or their `constructor`s, which were buggy. Just plain `object` with fields, methods, and inheritance. If only we could let `record` inherit from another `record`! See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/10/09/Good-old-object-is-not-to-be-deprecated-it-is-the-future

Comment: Inheritance (and virtual methods) only make sense if you need inheritance polymorphism, and that can only be had if the type is used as a reference type (IOW **not stack-based**). Inheritance of fields and methods for simple re-use can easily be had by aggregation.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I wrote inheritance without virtual methods.
I dot not agree with your POV. Aggregation of records is a real PITA, error prone and verbose. In some context, I use references (pointers) of stack-allocated records/objects, which are just fine. And for an array of records, references are also useful: you use the dynamic array as your "private heap" of continuous data, fitting right in the L1 cache, and easy to process e.g. using SSEx instructions. Such data structures are orders of magnitude faster to process than individual objects.

Comment: @Arnaud: not sure how objects and records differ there. You can use both through pointers. Aggregation is a bit more work than inheritance, sure, but not enough of a problem to keep on using TP-style objects, IMO. These things are deprecated, not supported very well and error prone. AFAIAC, they can remove them from the language, together with ShortStrings and all the other TP legacy stuff.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In practice, `object` is like removed, since its compiler support is buffy. Embarcadero can do whatever they want, but the more I see their decisions, the more I like FPC. Several object models in the same language do make sense: Java and C# heap-only approach is quite limited, and [new languages, like Rust, show up some new lights on Delphi](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/10/09/Good-old-object-is-not-to-be-deprecated-it-is-the-future). You may have never used such data structures, but I do everyday.

Comment: I use records a lot, especially now they can have methods and properties and operators and helpers and whatnot, but I can do without old objects.Haven't used them since Delphi 1. But I assume this is not the place to dicuss this.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `record` instead of `object` here:

```
type
  TMyTime = packed record
    Year: Word;
    Month: Byte;
    Day: Byte;
    Hour: Byte;
    Minute: Byte;
    Milliseconds: Word;
  end;
```

Or enable packing for the `object` scope itself:

```
type
  {$A-} // packed object
  TMyTime = object
  private
    Year: Word;
    Month: Byte;
    Day: Byte;
    Hour: Byte;
    Minute: Byte;
    Milliseconds: Word;
  end;
  {$A+} // default un-packed
```

The latter has the advantage of being compilable on Delphi 7 and newer versions.

For Delphi 2009 and later, try to avoid the use of `object` [which is buggy](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/01/29/record-and-object-issue-in-Delphi-2010). Use enhanced `record` types instead - but you lose inheritance...

Comment: Um, surely both the former **and** the latter are compilable on Delphi 7 and later ?  O.o

Comment: @Deltics Both are compatible with Delphi 7 or later, but if you need to add methods to the structure, the first won't allow this, whereas the later would. But due to issues in newer Delphi compiler when initializing objects containing managed types (like `string`), I usually write: `TMyStructure = {$ifndef UNICODE}object{$else}record{$endif}` ....